# How do I access an element of this JSON object created by JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using an AJAX POST to send a JSON object from the client side my server. However, I'm a little confused as to how to access the object once it gets there.

Here's my POST from the client side:

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({
       'app': 'reviews',
       'name': '',
       'review': '',
       'response': '',
       'rating': rating,
       'url': url,
       'date': date
     });
     console.log(data);
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "https://stormy-plateau-94715.herokuapp.com/",
           data: JSON.stringify(data),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
             alert(data['success']);
           },
           failure: function(errMsg) {
             alert(errMsg);
           }
       });
```

This works just fine. On my server, I print the body of the request and it looks fine:

```
"{\"app\":\"reviews\",\"name\":\"\",\"review\":\"\",\"response\":\"\",\"rating\":4.5,\"url\":\"test.com\",\"date\":\"7/5/2016\"}"
```

Then I call JSON.parse on it, and everything still works as I expected, here is the result:

{"app":"reviews","name":"","review":"","response":"","rating":4.5,"url":"test.com","date":"7/5/2016"}

This is saved in a variable called post. However, when I try to access post.app or post['app'], I get an undefined. Can anybody let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Use `$_POST['app']` on server side

Comment: why are you using `JSON.stringify` twice?

Comment: Poonam and FDavidov were right, I used stringify twice. I used console.log(post) to print the post variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very same issue happened to me when I mistakenly used `JSON.stringify` on an object that was already a string, which it looks is exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
   'app': 'reviews',
   'name': '',
   'review': '',
   'response': '',
   'rating': rating,
   'url': url,
   'date': date
 });
```

to

```
var data = {
   'app': 'reviews',
   'name': '',
   'review': '',
   'response': '',
   'rating': rating,
   'url': url,
   'date': date
 };
```